# How to get information from too array json in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a JSON file that has 2 arrays containing some data that I'd like to access on my AngularJS website. Now what I want is to get only one object from the 2 arrays.

**JSON data**

```
[
  {
    "DailyForecasts": [
      {
        "key": "32.48,44.46",
        "class": "forecast",
        "validDate": 1484236800,
        "maxTemp": 17,
        "minTemp": 3,
        "precip_type": "rain",
        "day": {
          "humid": 34,
          "wSpeed": 20,
          "wDir": 297,
          "pop": 0,
          "uv": 2,
          "icon": 34,
          "wDirText": "غرب-شمال غ",
          "phrase": "مشمس بصورة كلية",
          "bluntPhrase": "",
          "precip_type": "rain",
          "snwAccumPhrase": "",
          "snwAccumPhraseTerse": "",
          "extQual": "",
          "weatherCode": "3400"
        },
        "night": {
          "humid": 64,
          "wSpeed": 20,
          "wDir": 297,
          "pop": 0,
          "uv": 0,
          "icon": 33,
          "wDirText": "غرب-شمال غ",
          "phrase": "صافي بصورة كلية",
          "bluntPhrase": "",
          "precip_type": "precip",
          "snwAccumPhrase": "",
          "snwAccumPhraseTerse": "",
          "extQual": "",
          "weatherCode": "3300"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "32.48,44.46",
        "class": "forecast",
        "validDate": 1484323200,
        "maxTemp": 17,
        "minTemp": 5,
        "precip_type": "rain",
        "day": {
          "humid": 48,
          "wSpeed": 14,
          "wDir": 287,
          "pop": 0,
          "uv": 3,
          "icon": 32,
          "wDirText": "غرب-شمال غ",
          "phrase": "مشمس",
          "bluntPhrase": "",
          "precip_type": "rain",
          "snwAccumPhrase": "",
          "snwAccumPhraseTerse": "",
          "extQual": "",
          "weatherCode": "3200"
        },
        "night": {
          "humid": 67,
          "wSpeed": 14,
          "wDir": 287,
          "pop": 10,
          "uv": 0,
          "icon": 31,
          "wDirText": "غرب-شمال غ",
          "phrase": "صافي",
          "bluntPhrase": "",
          "precip_type": "rain",
          "snwAccumPhrase": "",
          "snwAccumPhraseTerse": "",
          "extQual": "",
          "weatherCode": "3100"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Controller Code**

```
 app.controller('Hillahctlr', function($scope, $http, wind, arrivecss, windname, icons) {
     $scope.wind_dir = wind;
     $scope.icons = icons;
     $scope.arrivecss = arrivecss;
     $scope.windname = windname;
     var service_url = "/key=e88d1560-a740-102c-bafd-001321203584&units=m&locale=ar&cb=JSON_CALLBACK";
     $http.jsonp(service_url)
         .success(
             function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 yData = data.HourlyForecasts;
                 $scope.ali = [];
                 for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                 {
                     $scope.ali[i] = {
                         dayes: yData[i].temp,
                     };
                 }
             })
 })
 }
```

and loop inside this array using ng-repeat , but its not working for me , this is code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ForecastArea-Day Last weatherteble" ng-repeat="alis in dayes">
   {{alis.dayes}}
</div>
```

I get this error: `Error: yData is not defined` Any help please ?

Comment: Where have you defined `HourlyForecasts`?

Comment: yes see update , data.HourlyForecasts

Comment: Your data does not have HourlyForecasts defined

Comment: can you log on your browser the data object by console.log(data) to check if the right structure for data

Comment: so ? am beginner can you please give me full answer . thanks

Comment: i have data console.log(data) but there no information in html

Comment: if you use chrome browser you can click on F12 to see the log on console

Comment: yData should be declared as either $scope.yData = data.HourlyForecasts; or var yData = data.HourlyForecasts;

Comment: Use `yData = data[0].HourlyForecasts;`. The JSON starts with [ { "DailyForecasts": [` which means it is an array of objects.

Comment: @georgeawg work , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `yData = data[0].HourlyForecasts;`. The JSON starts with `[ { "DailyForecasts": [` which means it is an array of objects.

---

> work fine thanks , what about the object day inside `HourlyForecasts`
>   when run get `yData[i].day` is `undefined`
>
> see my short code
>
> ```
> yday = data[0].DailyForecasts;
> $scope.daily = [];
> for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
>     $scope.daily[i] = {maxTemp: yData[i].maxTemp,
>                        minTemp: yData[i].minTemp,
>                        validDate: yData[i].validDate,
>                        icon: yData[i]day.icon, };
> }
> ```

All I see is a missing dot "`.`":

```
                   //    icon: yData[i]day.icon, };
                       icon: yData[i].day.icon, };
                   //                ^ --- put a dot here
```

Also be sure to declare `yday` as a var:

```
 //yday = data[0].DailyForecasts;
 var yday = data[0].DailyForecasts;
```

Without a `var` declaration, it will polute global namespace.

Comment: work fine thanks , what about the object `day` inside `HourlyForecasts` ! , when i try to do like this `yData = data[0].HourlyForecasts.day;` and when run get `yData[i].day is undefined`

Comment: see my short code `yday = data[0].DailyForecasts;
            $scope.daily = [];
   
            for(var i=0; i<9; i++)
            {
        $scope.daily[i] = {maxTemp: yData[i].maxTemp,
                        minTemp: yData[i].minTemp,
                        validDate: yData[i].validDate,
                        icon: yData[i]day.icon,

           };}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var alis = [];

 alis = {dayes: yData[i].temp,};
 $scope.ali = ali;

<div class="ForecastArea-Day Last weatherteble" ng-repeat="alis in ali.dayes"> 
{{alis.day}}
</div>
```

Comment: `Error: i is undefined`